# How to use curl/postman to access web page behind Azure AD Application Proxy

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

How can I use cURL or Postman to read a web page from behind Azure's AD Application Proxy?

I am trying to better understand how OAuth works in order to create some automation scripts that will need to access a server that we have behind an Application Proxy. Currently I am using a web browser and must sign in to my Microsoft account in order to view a web page hosted by the server. This works fine. Seeing as I am able to accomplish this without difficult using a web browser, it seems like I should also be able to accomplish the same using cURL or Postman.

The app that we have registered is registered as a confidential client (Microsoft's "Web App"). The public client option is disabled. It uses the Implicit Grant type to return an ID Token (The Access Token checkbox is not checked, only the ID Token checkbox). I don't have the ability to create a new client secret nor the ability to enable a public client type.

I have tried several of the different OAuth flows, but they all seem to require a client secret (because we are using the confidential client type), which I do not have access to. How am I able to read the web page through the browser despite not knowing any client secrets? How can I do the same via cURL or Postman?

Comment: To get the web application for confidential client type client secret is required. Or you need to use the implicit graph flow where user authentication is required.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses @Shiva-MSFTIdentity . If I understand you correctly, you are saying that all OAuth flows for confidential client types require a client secret except for the Implicit flow. This didn't solve my problem, but it is useful information and filled some gaps in my understanding, so thank you for that. I did eventually figure out a way to get through the proxy using Postman and I will detail my method below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being redirected to Microsoft's login page and logging in, Azure saves an access cookie in the browser. You can copy this access cookie and include it as part of a request in Postman. This will allow the request from Postman (or curl or whatever) to get to the service behind the Azure AD Application Proxy.

This is enough for my particular use case, but it does come with the problem of having to teach users how to find and copy the access cookie. It would be nice to find a more user-friendly way of getting the access cookie (or something similar).